# How do I extract just the blog content and exclude other elements using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the blog content from this [blog post](http://www.fashionpulis.com/2017/08/being-proud-too-soon.html) and by content, I just mean the first six paragraphs. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
body = soup.find('div', class_='post-body')
```

Printing `body` will also include other stuff under the main div tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www.fashionpulis.com/2017/08/being-proud-too-soon.html").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.select("div#post-body-604825342214355274"):
    print(item.text.strip())
```

Use this:

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www.fashionpulis.com/2017/08/acceptance-is-must.html").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.select("div[id^='post-body-']"):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I was wondering if there's a way for the scraper to be reused for similar blog posts. Example, [this one from the same site](http://www.fashionpulis.com/2017/08/acceptance-is-must.html) has a different id but similar format.

Comment: So, the post-body id has to be hard-coded each time?

Comment: Another way is `import re; soup.findAll('div', class_=re.compile('post-body'))`. BeautifulSoup handles that natively

Comment: @Bargain23, have you tried the both urls in the second script? It can grab content from both the sites as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution very interesting: [Scrape multiple pages with BeautifulSoup and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497722/scrape-multiple-pages-with-beautifulsoup-and-python)

However, I haven't found any Query String Parameters to tackle on, maybe you can start something out of this approach.

What I find most obvious to do right now is something like this:

1. Scrape through every month and year and get all titles from the Blog Archive part of the pages (e.g. on http://www.fashionpulis.com/2017/03/ and so on)
2. Build the URLs using the titles and the according months/years (the URL is always http://www.fashionpulis.com/$YEAR/$MONTH/$TITLE.html)
3. Scrape the text as described by Shahin in a previous answer