# Scrape several pages with the same url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape the data of this page (https://www.strava.com/segments/14533313) using beautifulsoop, or anything that works actually.

The url structure makes it hard for me to extract the data cause all the pages have the same url so it's trickier than just play with urls.

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I looked at the page. Is it the times you want? Or do you want it to crawl from that page?

Comment: What exactly do you want to scrape?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, I'd like to scrape the entire (category: all time) table from all pages, it should be similar to this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497722/scrape-multiple-pages-with-beautifulsoup-and-python) but I cant make it work

Comment: I actually solved the issue with the command &partial=false at the end of the url